# android sql - how do you order your sql query by multiple columns

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android project in Eclipse and i am having problems with my SQL query.

I am trying to order the query by more than two columns, currently i am doing it by KEY_DAY_ID but i want to also do it by KEY_START_TIME, but i can't get it to work

my query currently looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SESSION, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, 
            KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_DURATION, KEY_SESSION_TYPE, KEY_ROOM},
            null, null, null, null, KEY_DAY_ID  + " ASC");
```

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `KEY_DAY_ID  + ", " + KEY_START_TIME` (ASC is default) - should sort by day_id first and then by start_time

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The last parameter in db.query() method is the order by clause (without the "order by").  All you need to do is separate both columns by a ",".  So it would look like:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SESSION, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, 
        KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_DURATION, KEY_SESSION_TYPE, KEY_ROOM},
        null, null, null, null, KEY_DAY_ID + " ASC, " + KEY_START_TIME  + " ASC");
```

Comment: So which one has higher priority during sorting?

Comment: @AllenZeng the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do it in select line like this:

```
Cursor data = ddbb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM vacations ORDER BY NAME ,MONTH , date ",null);
```

in previous code the first probability for the first column "NAME" then will start arrange by the Second probability "MONTH" then the third  "date"..... 
which mean working in series
Or:

```
Cursor data = ddbb.rawQuery("select * from vacations where NAME = ? ORDER BY MONTH AND date ",new String[]{ns});
```

in previous code by using "AND" the two conditions are working together in parallel

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) db.query(DbHelper.TIMES, colmn, null, null, null, null, DbHelper.TABLE_DAY + " ASC, " + DbHelper.TABLE_LECTURE_NO + " ASC",null);
```